# Race condition Trying to read data from graphql immediately after writing the data

Tags: typescript, graphql, race-condition, hasura

i have an hasura grapql db, and i was performing the following operations:
i am looping through an array of events and based on some conditions, for example, if `event == paymentEvent`, i check if the user exists in my db, if it doesn't i have an `await client.mutate` action to write this user to db, in the else part, i also do the user check and write if it doesn't already exist, but somehow it seems that the write action does not complete before the check action in the next event in the loop, hence if i have an array of 2 events, propagated by the same user, one event is a payment event, the other is not, the write action in the first loop does not complete before the check in the else of the second loop, hence the else attempts to also write and at that point some sort of race condition happens and because the first write completes at this point and the second write throws an error:

```
for (let event of events) {
    if (event.type == payment) {
        // check if user exists
        let { data } = await client.query({
          query: user_query,
          variables: {id: event.user}
        })
        if (!data.User_by_pk) {
          await client.mutate({
            mutation: user_mutation,
            variables: {id: event.user}
          })
        } else {
          // i suppose the user check action can be put in a function to be called to tidy up.
          let { data } = await client.query({
          query: user_query,
          variables: {id: event.user}
         })
        if (!data.User_by_pk) {
          await client.mutate({
            mutation: user_mutation,
            variables: {id: event.user}
          })
        }
```

this results in user_pkey constraint error

i have tried to use a promise resolve to set some delay timeout after the first write, but i do not like the idea,
for now i am using a try catch mechanism to catch any constraint key error and just do nothing, because it means the user is already written, but i suppose there'll be a better way to approach this?
please let me know if i can make the question clearer or provide more context.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier, faster, & more reliable to do all this on the server instead of from the client?

Comment: @MichelFloyd i'm curious why you think this is not being done from the server?

Comment: Because of `client.mutate` and `client.query` - that tells me it's being done from a GraphQL client and not a GraphQL server.

Comment: ok.. maybe i'm doing it wrong then, i have an hasura db that i want to write to and read from, i suppose `client.mutate` and `query` was the way to go, no?